# Custom error mode in web.config not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, iis, web-config

I am trying to show a `.html` error page with back button when a user tries to upload a file greater than specific size. For the same i have added following code in my web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="13" />
  <error statusCode="404"
         subStatusCode="13"
         prefixLanguageFilePath=""
         path="Error.htm"
         responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
```

Application is deployed on `IIS8`. Now every thing is working well when i am testing in localhost, but as soon as i deploy my application on Servers (My application is deployed on two different Machines on IIS 8 and accessed via a common URL) then from 'Error.html' page my HTML back button is not working. On Back button click event i am getting `This page can not be displayed` and nothing in the page works until we press f5 to refresh the page.Here is my `Back` button code..

```
 <TD height=41 align=center><button onclick="history.go(-1);" type=button>Back</button></TD>
```

What is being wrong here ?

Comment: What warnings are displayed in the dev tool console? this one? DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
 A common design pattern is to use a SESSION variable to flag that a user has successfully logged on, then in the pageload event handler in the code behind, test if that SESSION variable is not blank.... Redirect to the previously visited page or your site landing page if they are already logged in....

Comment: Don't use `history.go(-1);` on error pages, what if the previous page generated that error even without a PostBack? The user would be immediately send back to the same error page. Better just link to the homepage.